# Is there a "natural" example of a probability space where the singletons aren't measurable?

Tags: probability-theory

Is there a "natural" example of a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ such that $\bigcup_{\omega \in \Omega} \{\{\omega\}\} \not\subset \mathcal{F}$? Here by "natural" I mean something which might be of independent interest to probabilists, or has an intuitive probabilistic interpretation.

Of course, there are many natural examples where we have a *sub*-$\sigma$-algebra which does not contain the singletons, and often (e.g., in the context of conditional expectation) this is of interest. However, in this question, I'm referring to the *ambient* probability space.

If there is such an example, how should we interpret this? It would seem very strange for the elementary outcomes $\{\omega\}$ to not be measurable. This would mean, for instance, the natural "random variable" $\mathbf{1}_{\{\omega\}}$ isn't even a random variable!

Comment: I don't think there are natural examples, but I also don't see what's strange and concerning about this. If we're picking a random number from $[0,1]$, the outcomes $\{x\}$ are measurable and have measure $0$, of course, but they're not *interesting*. We never have any use for the random variable $\mathbf 1_{\{x\}}$. So if these weren't measurable, would we miss them?

Comment: If all you know is the probability  of events of interest of a sigma-algebra, though physically there must be a deeper set of singletons for which you have no probabilistic information, would that count as non-measurable?

Comment: The usual example of (finitely/infinitely) many indistinguishable objects is probably the most natural example here.  You are not allowed to distinguish those indistinguishable objects so singleton isn't measurable.  Of course if you "cheat" and embed it into a larger $\sigma$-algebra then you can make singletons measurable.